# Delete shared preferences after app uninstall without using android:allowBackup="false"

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, uninstallation, android-backup-service

I want to delete sharedpreferences after the app is uninstalled. And I dont want to use the  **android:allowBackup="false"** option as I read that it is not recommended for apps in production. Is there any other way we can delete the shared preferences for an app after uninstalling while still preserving backups(During upgrades)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You can use `BroadcastReceiver` for it</del>

<del>Add this to `Manifest`</del>

```
<receiver android:name=".DeleteReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

<del>And `BroadcastReceiver` class</del>

```
public class DeleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //remove preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** after some research I found that you [cannot receive something when your app is deleted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).

> The package that is being removed does not receive this Intent.

The only solution is to use second application to get it. Sorry for disappointing.

So in your case `android:allowBackup=“false”` is the **only** way to delete settings.

Comment: I tried this.But it is not working for me.I kept the receiver class outside all activities is that correct ?

Comment: @Bharath yes it should be separatly in its own file. Did you check that your device doesnt block receivers?

Comment: @DeadMC- I think my device doesnt block receivers. Is there any way I can check ? I am new to Android development. So if you can give me pointers it will be of great help

Comment: @Bharath what device do you use?

Comment: I use Google Nexus 5

Comment: @Bharath ehh updated post, really no other solutions.

Comment: Ok Thanks. .Just want one more info, if I use android:allowBackup=“false” for any object live in production. . Wouldnt it also prevent my backup and if there is any upgrade to the app, all the previous data stored in Shared preferences will be lost rite ?

Comment: @Bharath I use android:allowBackup=“false” and it works fine with updates but I cant say something about backups. Anyway, how many people use backups of apps? Also if data is really important better to keep it in Firebase or somewhere else.

Comment: Got your point. I was initially under the impression that Shared prefernces will be removed after updates if I use android:allowBackup=“false”. Now Wrote a short code to perform the functionality I needed